# Изменить порт хостинга в Net 6.0

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net, .net-6

Не могу сделать банальную вещь- поменять порт при запуске проекта в Net 6.0 в Visual Studio 2022. Раньше это делалось в свойствах проекта, сейчас там нет возможности поменять. Нашел информацию что можно прописать в launchsettings.json - изменил там для "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development", а как изменить для Release версии?

Comment: нашел файл launchSettings в разделе Properties, пробую настроить там.

Comment: Эм, если хостите через IIS, то и за порт отвечает IIS. ПКМ по сайт - Изменить привязки, там и настраиваете какой порт, домент, сертификат, и др. будет использоваться.

Comment: По "сайт"- что понимается под сайтом? Сам проект? Там не нашел "Изменить привязки".

Comment: [может тут найдете ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70332897/how-to-change-default-port-no-of-my-net-core-6-api)

Comment: Ну как-же, [вот](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yhjdl.png). Ищите внимательней, должен быть пункт, где вы указываете ip адрес, домен, и др. информацию о сайте.